# ComboBox selected text or item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working in winform I try a lot of times to catch the text of the comboBox selected item, and I can not, it's always empty, this is code

```
List<person>op = new List<person>(); op=DAL_O.per();
        foreach(person rt in op )
        {
            comboBox1.DataSource = op;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name_person";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "id_person";
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      Lbl_full_list.Text+=comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
//or
      Lbl_full_list.Text+= comboBox1.Text;


    }
```

Maybe someone has an idea? I searched a lot on Google and the results did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding code is incorrect.

Removing the `foreach` around it, should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you don't want to bind each person in the list to the combo box otherwise you'' only have a maximum of one item in the list, you just want to bind the whole list so remove the loop. And also you can combine the list declaration and setting into one line to get this (you could even skip using List, but I've left it in for readablity:

```
List<person>op = DAL_O.per();

comboBox1.DataSource = op;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name_person";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "id_person";
```

And as for getting the selected text value, I'd use either

```
comboBox1.Text
```

or ([as per MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx))

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the list

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are you using `foreach` loop? You can bind it simple like this:

```
List<person>op = new List<person>(); 
op=DAL_O.per();
comboBox1.DataSource = op;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name_person";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "id_person";
```

And regarding your original question, try:

```
Lbl_full_list.Text += comboBox1.Text
```

Comment: Why post the same solution as the 2 previous answers? It adds no extra information...

Comment: when i started writing there wasnt any and the internet connection i am using is somewhat slow to automatically notify me about answers already posted while I was writing..

Comment: No problem :) It happens with me too.